# extend mean module findOne() to handle other attributes that strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, angular-promise

When start a new meanjs project (mongoose, angular etc.) using the generator and add a CRUD-module i get methods like this:

```
    $scope.findOne = function() {
        $scope.income = Incomes.get({
            incomeId: $stateParams.incomeId
    });
```

In my income server model is shown below, it has some different attributes and some different object types on these attributes, for example, number, date and string.

When i get data in my $scope.income after the promise "$scope.findOne" has succeded all my data are strings. Do i need to cast each and every one of them to their proper type?

In my front end i want to present the different types in the input elements of my "update" view. For example:

```
          <label class="control-label" for="date">Date of transaction</label>
            <div class="list-group-item">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" data-ng-model="income.date" id="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required>
                </div>
```

This does not work since the object $scope.income.date consists of a string. Changing the input type to string makes it show up. But I want to use a date picker here.

Should I write something like:

```
        $scope.findOne = function() {
        Incomes.get({
            incomeId: $stateParams.incomeId
        }).then(function(data){
            var dateVar=new Date(data.date);
            var amountVar =Number(data.amount) 
            $scope.income ={date: dateVar, name: data.name, amount:amountVar}()
        );
```

What is best practise here?

Model I am using:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Income Schema
 */
var IncomeSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Income name',
        trim: true
    },
    amount: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      required: 'Please fill Income amount',
      trim: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Income date',
        trim: true
    },
    monthly: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill whether income is recurring monthly',
        trim: true
    },
    yearly: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: '',
      required: 'Please fill whether income is recurring yearly',
      trim: true
    },
    account: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Account',
      required: 'Please select account'

  },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Income', IncomeSchema);
```

Comment: db schema has nothing to do with how the data is sent> Sounds like something wrong in output code (controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the resources function for remove work properly "this" needed to be used, dont forget that the promise is in another namespace so "that=this" is needed.

```
  var that=this;
  Incomes.get({
    incomeId: $stateParams.incomeId
  }).$promise.then(function(income){

        income.date= new Date(income.date);

        var recurringVar;
        if(income.monthly===true){
          recurringVar = 'monthly';
        } else if( income.yearly===true){
          recurringVar = 'yearly';
        }
        income.recurring=recurringVar;
        that.income=income;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

First I had to get a hold of the promise, than I easily could build more complex objects from the Incomes.get response. The data is sent over the network as JSON and there fore it is just text, so I needed to instantiate it to the proper types using f ex. Date and Number:

```
   Incomes.get({
                incomeId: $stateParams.incomeId
            }).$promise.then(function(data){
                var dateVar=new Date(data.date);
                var amountVar =Number(data.amount) 
                $scope.income ={date: dateVar, name: data.name, amount:amountVar}()
            );
```

Comment: Using this solution, somehow the object is malformed so that the remove function of resources dont work, a better solution is posted using this/that